# Android Complex list of items in scrollview Best Practices

Tags: android, list, scrollview

I´m developing an app in which I have a list of products, sometimes are a huge list and other times are only one or two items.

I read this items from a local database, right? ok, when I have about 20 o 30 items, I think the return is very slow, it takes one or two seconds rendering items and I need to know the best practices about that.
I have tested two ways:

- The more tricky (I think), is creating views programmatically and adding to the scrollview as childs of the linearlayout inside.
- The best for design: having an item-theme in a xml and inflating once by each item.

Is there a better way? I´m sure yes!

My items are a little bit complex:
image, name, category, provider, price, some buttons with "onclick" listeners, two little icons. Everything each item.

It is very important for me to speed up that process.

Comment: Can you add the code to your list adapter and the xml layout/code used for each list item please ? It would help us help you ;-)

Comment: No, I´m not using a listview, only a linearlayout vertical... it might be the problem right? I read something about array adapter to a listview, is the better way? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the answer](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview). Really cool.

Answer (score 1):

you can use listview and use the attr :
android:descendantFocusability=”blocksDescendants”

it can make your item widget respond some click or touch

Comment: Thanks but... I think you misunderstand my question.

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts on what you described are:

- Create an xml layout for the listing
- When you get the full list of items, store listing data somewhere
- Inflate 5 (or 10 or whatever a reasonable amount of might be) listing layouts into the scroll view and use the data to fill them
- Use a listener to check when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the scroll view... or halfway down or whatever you choose
- Inflate the next set of items if they exist

This should prevent the slowdown and if you implement it correctly the user won't even know they aren't all loaded.

I think you need to implement a scroll view type to do this... do some searching for the scrollviewlistener.

It should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: mmm... it sounds good, but could be a little bit tricky or not? I will investigate the scrollviewlistener, because would be nice.

Comment: This answer is Ok, but it's been some time since it was posted, so I would like to add that, at the time of writing this message, it's recommended to use RecyclerView in order to avoid slowing down your app if you have many items on your list, or if those items are complex and contain many different views within them. You can find more information here: [RecyclerViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) I believe using RecyclerViews will save you a couple of this steps too.